# How to render partials on page load within a Haml file in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, partial-views

How do I render a partial from within a JavaScript tag in a Haml file?

I want the Save button to be displayed when the page has finished loading.

At the moment, the file (partial) looks like this:

```
.form-group.form-actions
  .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
    %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "submit", name: "save"
      %i.icon-white.icon-ok
      = t("Save")
```

I moved the `%button.btn.btn-primary` section into another partial file, `_save_button.html.haml` and tried the following:

```
.form-group.form-actions
  .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
    :javascript
      $(document).ready( function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "<%= render partial: 'save_button' %>" ,
          success: function(data){
            //if ever there is something more to do (there is also an error handler)
          }
        });
      });
```

This had no affect though, the Save button did not show up.

How can I load the partial on load?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? If so, you'll want to listen for `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->` as described in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks). Also, I don't know what you think `url: "<%= render partial: 'save_button' %>"` is going to / supposed to do, but it looks like a hot mess to me.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it looks as though you're using ERB syntax in your URL. The `<%=` opening is not HAML syntax.

As for rendering the partial within the JavaScript method, I don't think Ajax is what you want. You're already using `$(document).ready` so anything you execute in there should happen after the document has loaded.

Comment: Yeah good point, not sure what I was going for with that one.

I've tried this now:
`:javascript
      $(document).ready( function() {
        #{ = render :partial => 'save_button'}
      });`

I get `unexpected '=' #{= render :partial => 'save_button'}` when trying to run

Comment: Got rid of the "=" sign and it ran ok. My save button did not appear though unfortunately and I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' " in my chrome console

Comment: That's because Javascript doesn't understand HAML syntax - unfortunately, I don't believe you're going to be able to render Ruby from HAML inside Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can render a Haml partial inside JavaScript code, but you need to escape the HTML so the browser doesn't think it's code:

```
someHtml = "#{ j render(partial: 'your_partial') }";
```

`j` is a shortcut for `escape_javascript`.

You want `#{ ... }` instead of `<%= ... %>` for Haml.